# Google project used over multiple web pages

Tags: google-people-api

I have a google console project which utiilises People API. I have a standalone webpage which works perfectly well for oauth and api key. However, when I put the code on another page, adding the page url in the project settings, etc, it says "the api key and the authentication credentials are from different projects".

It is in the same project, the only difference is that it uses a different page.

Comment: Could you please give a better context to your problem? What do you mean by *another page* ? Your *standalone webpage* is a [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)? Please add some code, too

Answer (score 0):

When creating the oauth token in the google api console, I believe you have to specify an authorized redirect url. If the url of your new page does not correspond with the authorized url set for the oauth token, access will be denied.

For exemple, if I set `localhost:8000/authorize` as the url (for dev work), using it with anything else (ex. `www.mywebsite.com/authorize`, `localhost:8000/access`, etc) will not work.